# PHP/MySQL/PDO -- Unable to UPDATE Default or zero values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

On a table of books, some rows might not have complete data. However, the Admin can edit the rows. In this case, the Admin is updating the row by adding a publication year where there was none (year_pub was inserted blank).

MySQL/PDO UPDATE on this `INT(4)` column does not work for some reason.

The field year_pub is non-null.

Here's the code:

```
$year_pub = filter_var($_POST['year'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$id_book = filter_var($_POST[‘id’], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

/*
*   DB CONNECT
*/

$query = "UPDATE table_books SET year_pub=:year_pub WHERE id_book=:id_book";
$stmt = $dbH->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":year_pub", $year_pub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(":id_book", $id_book, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here are some results:

---

[year_pub field has a Default Value]

If Default is 0
    UPDATE does not work.

If Default is 1
    UPDATE does not work.

However, a second attempt to UPDATE does work.

---

[year_pub field has no Default Value] (‘placeholder’ value instead)

if `placeholder` value is 0
    UPDATE does not work

if `placeholder` value is 1
    UPDATE works

---

This is very strange behavior. I've never seen this before. Can someone explain what might be happening here?

Comment: First thing I noticed is the weird colouring of your code due to different kind of quotes, I would look into that first.

Comment: Okay, I think I see it now in the code block. The Post key 'year' is highlighted in red. Now I realize my mistake. The actual field in the DB is simply 'year', which is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: It was cut-and-paste from an RTF. That is strange.

Comment: @Dev `year` is not reserved. The coloring is because of the smart quote with the standard quote. The `(R)` indicates reserved terms.

Comment: @Dev RTF files (i.e. Wordpad or MS Word) don't use a proper double quote character.

Comment: Table 10.2 -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score -1):

The sample code wasn't accurate. The actual query was:

```
$query = "UPDATE table_books SET year=:year WHERE id_book=:id_book";
```

The column had been named 'year'. Changing the column name to 'year_pub', like it should have been named, fixed the problem.

Comment: You should just delete the question in that case because the issue was a typo, not a programming issue.